# Is there a way to pull in system enums eg DayOfWeek, using ReinforcedTypings

Tags: reinforced-typings

Using System.DayOfWeek enum within my own custom type, resolves to 'any' - is there a way to have it resolved?

I am using only attributes so far and can't see any way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it can be achieved only with fluent configuration. See [substitutions](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Types-Resolution#substitutions) for more details.
Fluent configuration is backward-compatible with attributes configuration, so enabling fluent configuration for your project will not be painful.